# Selenium Webdriver : Getting NoSuchElementException after switching window

Tags: java, window, selenium-webdriver

```
I switch from window A to window B.When i try to perform an action on window B,it throws No such element exception.I am new to selenium webdriver.Please help me out.
```

My requirement :
1)Go to http://www.kotak.com/bank/personal-banking/convenience-banking/net-banking.html
2)Click on SECURELY LOGIN
3)Switch to the newly opened window and fill username and password in it.Locating username and password on this window throwing error.

```
     My code :


    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Set;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class WindowHandler1 {


public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
{

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();     

    driver.get("http://www.kotak.com/bank/personal-banking/convenience-                   banking/net-banking.html");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='label-01']/a[1]")).click();
    Set<String> windowids = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> iter = windowids.iterator();
            System.out.println(windowids);

    String mainWindowId = iter.next();
    String tabedWindowId = iter.next();
    Thread.sleep(2000L);

            // switching to the new pop up window
            driver.switchTo().window(tabedWindowId);

            Thread.sleep(20000);

            //getting no such element exception upon executing  line below 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Username']")).sendKeys("username");
            driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).sendKeys("abc");
```

}
}

Comment: Someone answered a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7468092/1567184

Comment: check it out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338530/selenium-to-close-the-window1-and-focus-on-another/17339871#17339871

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and noticed that in the list of window handles from selenium, the order is not always the same. So in your code it looks like you are dependent on the last window in the list being the new window, when it may be the first. The solution was to make sure that the window you are trying to switch to is not the same as the current window handle.

You may be getting the NoSuchElement exception because you are not in the right window.